# Unable to search through encrypted value from sqlite database

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to find a recored with an encrypted string like

```
description = "oYAFfrNS2OszASY7Vo182A=="
```

and it is stored in sqlite database like

```
oYAFfrNS2OszASY7Vo182A==
```

in the description field.

My android code is:

```
Cursor c = db.query(table, columns, 
                whereclause, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);          
  try {
    if (c.getCount() == 0) {
      c.close(); 
      return "";
    }
    c.moveToFirst();   

    int namecol = c.getColumnIndex(columns[0]);       
    li = (c.getString(namecol));            
    c.close();    
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception:   " + e.toString());
  }
```

where table name, where clause and columns all are correct for sure but I am unable to get the result with encrypted string which I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem by debugging further actually there is one new line character in my encrypted string which were not passed in this.